# jQuery stop fixed header on footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed header, positioned at the bottom, and I want it to stop on the footer. I have written some code, but it's not working.

Here's the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarafa/dr0c2va5/15/)

And here's the script:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var headerTop = $('#shopify-section-header').offset().top;
    var headerHeight = $('.header-wrap').height();
    var footerTop = $('footer').offset().top;
    var footerHeight = $('footer').height();

    if (headerTop + headerHeight > footerTop){
      console.log('okay')
      $('#shopify-section-header').css({'position':'absolute', 'bottom': footerHeight + headerHeight});
    } else{
      console.log('nothing')
      $('#shopify-section-header').css({'position':'fixed', 'bottom': '0'});
    };
  });
```

EDIT: I have worked on it, way better, it works well, until I go up. See working example: [JSFiddle - 2](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarafa/dr0c2va5/22/)

And here's the updated script:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var headerTop = $('.header').offset().top;
    var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
    var footerTop = $('.footer').offset().top;
    var footerHeight = $('.footer').height();

    if (headerTop + headerHeight > footerTop){
      $('.header').css({'position':'absolute', 'top': footerTop - headerHeight});
    } else if (headerTop + headerHeight < footerTop){
      console.log('nothing')
      $('.header').css({'position':'fixed', 'bottom': '0'});
    };
});
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: In your jsfiddle you haven't included Jquery

Comment: Also you have no element with the id `shopify-section-header`

Comment: Do you need it? - https://ibb.co/8zZtx6P

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen all fixed! Could you check now?

Comment: @BenjaminCarafa You haven't updated the link

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen done

Comment: Do you need to use Javascript for this? You can accomplish what I think you're asking for with fewer lines using css `position: sticky`

Comment: @CallumMorrisson I tried to implement `sticky` on another element in my page and it didn't work because I have a few `overflow: hidden` which I can't change in order to make these work. Still, if you'd like, leave the answer, I'll try, and maybe it's useful for someone else

Comment: Your question is about JQuery, it would be annoying for next guy if the answer is to use `position: sticky`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so at the end I went with a different approach: by checking whether the footer is visible in the viewport. If so, it would stick, else not.

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var headerTop = $('.header').offset().top;
    var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
    var footerTop = $('.footer').offset().top;
    var footerHeight = $('.footer').height();
    var footerVisible = $('.footer').isInViewport()

        if (footerVisible){
         $('.header').css({'position':'absolute', 'top': footerTop - headerHeight});
    } else if (footerVisible == false) {
         $('.header').css({'position':'fixed', 'bottom': '0', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
    
});


$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

Note that this works for me because I have the header `fixed` with `bottom: 0`.